# Event Hub, Stream Analytics and Data Lake pipe questions

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

After reading this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-data-lake-output) I decided to take a shot on building a pipe of data ingestion. Everything works well. I was able to send data to Event Hub, that is ingested by Stream Analytics and sent to Data Lake. But, I have a few questions regarding some things that seem odd to me. I would appreciate if someone more experienced than me is able to answer.

Here is the SQL inside my Stream Analytics

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    [my-data-lake]
FROM
    [my-event-hub]
```

Now, for the questions:

1. Should I store 100% of my data in a single file, try to split it in multiple files, or try to achieve one-file-per-object? Stream Analytics is storing all the data inside a single file, as a huge JSON array. I tried setting {date} and {time} as variables, but it is still a huge single file everyday.
2. Is there a way to enforce Stream Analytics to write every entry from Event Hub on its own file? Or maybe limit the size of the file?
3. Is there a way to set the name of the file from Stream Analytics? If so, is there a way to override a file if a name already exists?
4. I also noticed the file is available as soon as it is created, and it is written in real time, in a way I can see data truncation inside it when I download/display the file. Also, before it finishes, it is not a valid JSON. What happens if I query a Data Lake file (through U-SQL) while it is being written? Is it smart enough to ignore the last entry, or understand it as an array of objects that is incomplete?
5. Is it better to store the JSON data as an array or each object in a new line?

Maybe I am taking a bad approach on my issue, but I have a huge dataset in Google Datastore (NoSQL solution from Google). I only have access to the Datastore, with an account with limited permissions. I need to store this data on a Data Lake. So I made an application that streams the data from Datastore to Event Hub, that is ingested by Stream Analytics, who writes down the files inside the Data Lake. It is my first time using the three technologies, but seems to be the best solution. It is my go-to alternative to ETL chaos.

I am sorry for making so much questions. I hope someone helps me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the Azure Event Hubs Capture feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-enable-through-portal for direct storing your pipeline (raw) stream data  into the Azure Storage container or Azure Data Lake Store based on your windowing (time/size) needs.

Comment: @RomanKiss thank you! This makes a lot of sense! I have some "logic" on my Stream Analytics, but I might ignore it and go straight to the Event Hub Capture solution.

Comment: The captured stream can be used directly for warm & cold pipelines besides the hot (real-time) pipeline from the ingested data in the Event Hub and analyzed via the ASA jobs..

Comment: @RomanKiss sorry, I am not very experienced. What do you consider a warm or cold pipeline? In my scenario, I pretty much have data coming from different data sources, and based on a "data_source" JSON attribute, I must archive it to a different folder in the data lake. But, AFAIK, straight from Event Hubs Capture, I can't define a conditional path within.

Comment: The Azure Event Hubs Capture feature allows to archive ingested telemetry data based on the partitioned consumer model (each partition is stored separately file). Maximum number of the partitions for Event Hubs is 32, so if your numOfsources are <= 32, than your puller app needs to push a data to the specific partition of the EH based on the "data_source" attribute.That's the hardcoded static design when the data source is mapped to the partition of the EH. More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only going to answer the file aspect:

1. It is normally better to produce larger files for later processing than many very small files. Given you are using JSON, I would suggest to limit the files to a size that your JSON extractor will be able to manage without running out of memory (if you decide to use a DOM based parser).
2. I will leave that to an ASA expert.
3. ditto.
4. The answer depends here on how ASA writes the JSON. Clients can append to files and U-SQL should only see the data in a file that has been added in sealed extents. So if ASA makes sure that extents align with the end of a JSON document, you should be only seeing a valid JSON document. If it does not, then you may fail.
5. That depends on how you plan on processing the data. Note that if you write it as part of an array, you will have to wait until the array is "closed", or your JSON parser will most likely fail. For parallelization and be more "flexible", I would probably get one JSON document per line.

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael. I will attempt some advances this week and hopefully I will be able to set up ASA properly